# Matplotlib doesn't plot certain data..although scatter works

Tags: matplotlib, plot

say

```
twenty = [[0.00186157 0.00201416 0.00216675 0.00213623 0.00253296 0.00250244  0.00280762 0.00292969 0.00308228 0.0032959  0.00338745 0.003479  0.003479   0.00341797 0.00335693 0.00320435 0.00308228 0.0027771  0.00253296 0.00216675]]
twentyfirst = [[0.00186157]]
```

Following function - while it should plot for both scatter as well as lineplot, (this is implemented exactly as in the [page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)) Got as far as to plot both in markers, but the `matplotlib` is lost in generating lines.

```
def plot_time_series(twenty, twentyfirst):
    xlabel = np.arange(0, 1, 1./20).reshape(1,20)
    print(np.ones(twenty.shape[1])[np.newaxis,:].shape) #(1,20)
    A = np.vstack([xlabel, np.ones(twenty.shape[1])[np.newaxis,:]]).T

    m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, twenty.T)[0]
    print(m, c)
    plt.scatter(xlabel, twenty.T, c='b', label='data')
    ylabel = m*xlabel + c
    print(ylabel.shape) #(1,20)
    plt.plot(xlabel, ylabel, '-ok', label = 'fitted line')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.ylabel('amplitudes')
    plt.savefig('timeseries_problem2'+'_4')
    plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: All the reshaping that happens in the code is much too confusing. Why not work with 1D arrays throughout? If you really want/need to do it this way, I suppose you need to transpose the plot values as well, `plt.plot(xlabel.T, ylabel.T)`.

Comment: These are 1d, just the length is long.

Comment: They are not 1D, else you would get a couple of errors from your code. Does the above suggestion not work?

Comment: you are asking me to explain `linalg.lstsq` to you. I dont see your point of transposing when I can already plot. Its the line -

Comment: When you replace `plt.plot(xlabel, ylabel, '-ok', label = 'fitted line')` by `plt.plot(xlabel.T, ylabel.T, '-ok', label = 'fitted line')`, the plot will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueY4z.png). I suppose this is what you're after. Or if not, consider clarifying inside the question.

Comment: so if the input arrays are row.. it takes each column element as a separate plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, this question asks about the difference between plotting

```
plt.plot([[1,2,3]],[[2,3,1]])
```

and

```
plt.plot([[1],[2],[3]],[[2],[3],[1]])
```

In both cases the lists are 2 dimensional. In the first case, you have a single row of data. In the second case you have a single column of data.

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html):

> `x`, `y` : array-like or scalar
> [...]
> Commonly, these parameters are arrays of length N. However, scalars are supported as well (equivalent to an array with constant value).
>
> The parameters can also be **2-dimensional**. Then, the **columns represent separate data sets**.

The important part is the last sentence. If data is 2D, as here, it is interpreted column-wise. Since the row-array `[[2,3,1]]` consists of 3 columns, each with a single value. `plot` will hence produce 3 single "lines" with one point. But since a single point defines no line, it will only be visible when activating the marker, e.g.

```
plt.plot([[1,2,3]], [[2,3,1]], marker="o")
```

[image]

When transposing this row array to a column array, it will be interpreted as a single dataset with 3 entries. Hence the desired outcome of a single line

```
plt.plot([[1],[2],[3]], [[2],[3],[1]])
```

[image]

Of course flattening the array to 1D is equally possible,

```
plt.plot(np.array([[1,2,3]]).flatten(), np.array([[2,3,1]]).flatten())
```

You may easily check how many lines you produced

```
print(len(plt.plot([[1,2,3]],[[2,3,1]])))            # prints 3
print(len(plt.plot([[1],[2],[3]],[[2],[3],[1]])))    # prints 1
```

Comment: This explains the multiple legends (by the number of columns) as well. Thank you so much.